# In the pit in The Dark Knight Rises, where was the rope tied?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

The rope hanging in the pit has the end tied up near the top of the well, or somewhere around midway. So why didn't the climbers directly used the rope to climb rather than climbing manually? Is this a plot hole or am I missing something?

Comment: I have no fact to back this up but it could be that the rope is tied in such a way that you couldn't move from top of the rope to the jump spot or the rope to the climbing route to the jump spot.

Comment: Based on the picture supplied it looks like there is certainly a route to the jump spot. hmmmm raises some good points too! Looks like a plot hole to me.

Comment: This article mention this plot hole http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2012/07/30/the_dark_knight_rises_climbing_scenes_don_t_make_any_sense_at_all.html

Comment: Also, the sheer force created when he falls would almost definitely break the rope (about 6KN...I highly doubt the rope would take roughly 600KGs!). And if it didn't break (which it doesn't) he would be ripped in half. A bit silly really.

Comment: Looking at that picture. The distance to the top of the pit isnt that much so the rope tied round bruce cound be thrown with a loop on it up and out of the pit, then climbed. Of course there wouldnt be the drama of the trying!

Comment: It doesn't matter one bit. the whole scene and movie makes no real sense. It was written and shown to only be an analogy for morality.

Answer (score 30):

A [**screenshot**](http://theshootening.com/2011/12/20/news-the-dark-knight-rises-official-trailer-released/) from the trailer shows that the rope doesn't go all the way to the top:

[image: Pit]

Answer (score 17):

The rope they used to secure themselves with was not tied to the top of the pit. You can see it ending somewhere beneath the "jump spot".

Bruce Wayne lowers a second pile of rope into the pit, after escaping.

Answer (score 5):

This scene (or the few climbing scenes have a few problems). Surely Bruce could have climbed up the rope and then to the jump point, it would have been a bit faster and easier. However my main problem with these scenes is when Bruce falls.

First the man at the bottom holding the rope should be pulling tight on the rope all the time so when someone falls the rope catches them almost immediately instead of having to fall a long way first.

Secondly after falling a long way the rope catches bruce, however falling this distance and then being caught by a normal rope just tied around the waist would surely break his back (and damage other organs as well) especially as he already had his back broken.

I would have also thought that Bruce could have fashioned some sort of grappling hook and once he had reached the jump section just use that to climb out.